# insert DEFAULT values

Tags: postgresql, insert, default, default-value

Is there ANY difference between those two statements?:

```
INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'XYZ Widgets');
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO distributors (dname) VALUES ('XYZ Widgets');
```

I mean is there at least one reason to use one or another pattern in some particular situation or is it completely the same? 
did is a serial column.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's exactly the same thing. No need to pick one instead of the other.

Usually `default` keyword is handy when you have computer-generated code. It makes life easier to just use every single column in the insert clause and just use `default` when you don't have a specific value for certain column.

Other than that, as I said, it's the same.

Comment: `default` is also very handy when you want to indicate an `insert` that used default values for every single column.

Comment: useful if you are using a sequence and want to get the new value with returning.
`insert into table(id) values(DEFAULT) returning id;`

Answer (score 6):

```
INSERT INTO distributors (dname) VALUES ('XYZ Widgets');
```

This is fine, you do not need to specify a field if you want its default value being saved, provided a default is set.