# Postgres error: null value in column "id" - during insert operation

Tags: sql, postgresql, yii, null, sql-insert

I use postgresql and yii2 framework.
Well I got a very interesting error message:

```
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, 1, null, null, null, null, 1, Demo, , , , 1998-01-01, , , , 345345435453453, , , , , 1, , , f, f, f, f, 10, f, 1, f, f, f, null, null, null, 1470477479, 1470477479, null).
```

But I checked my Insert command, and there is not "id" column there!

```
INSERT INTO "advertiser" ("languages", "type", "name", "display_name", "title", "about", "birthday", "gender", "country_id", "county_id", "city_id", "city_part", "street", "house_number", "phone", "public_email", "public_url", "motto", "message", "im_facebook", "im_skype", "has_viber", "has_whatsapp", "has_sms_response", "visible_birthday", "is_checked", "status", "version", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (NULL, 1, 'Demo', '', '', '', '1998-01-01', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', '', '345345435453453', '', '', '', '', '', '', FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 10, NULL, 1, 1470477479, 1470477479) RETURNING "id"
```

So I really cannot understand this error message. I do not find that the Postgres or Yii try to insert a null ID value or what.

By the way here you can find the structure

```
                                                    Table "public.advertiser"
        Column         |          Type          |            Modifiers            | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                    | integer                | not null                        | plain    |              | 
 user_id               | integer                |                                 | plain    |              | 
 country_id            | integer                |                                 | plain    |              | 
 county_id             | integer                |                                 | plain    |              | 
 city_id               | integer                |                                 | plain    |              | 
 district_id           | integer                |                                 | plain    |              | 
 type                  | smallint               |                                 | plain    |              | 
 name                  | character varying(255) | not null                        | extended |              | 
 display_name          | character varying(255) | default NULL::character varying | extended |              | 
 title                 | character varying(255) | default NULL::character varying | extended |              | 
 about                 | text                   |                                 | extended |              | 
 birthday              | date                   | not null                        | plain    |              | 
 city_part             | character varying(255) | default NULL::character varying | extended |              | 
 street                | character varying(255) | default NULL::character varying | extended |              | 
 house_number          | character varying(20)  | default NULL::character varying | extended |              | 
 phone                 | character varying(15)  | not null                        | extended |              | 
 public_email          | character varying(255) | default NULL::character varying | extended |              | 
 public_url            | character varying(255) | default NULL::character varying | extended |              | 
 motto                 | character varying(255) | default NULL::character varying | extended |              | 
 message               | text                   |                                 | extended |              | 
 gender                | smallint               | not null default 1              | plain    |              | 
 im_facebook           | character varying(255) | default NULL::character varying | extended |              | 
 im_skype              | character varying(255) | default NULL::character varying | extended |              | 
 has_viber             | boolean                | not null default false          | plain    |              | 
 has_whatsapp          | boolean                | not null default false          | plain    |              | 
 has_sms_response      | boolean                | not null default false          | plain    |              | 
 visible_birthday      | boolean                | not null default false          | plain    |              | 
 status                | smallint               | not null default 10             | plain    |              | 
 is_checked            | boolean                | not null default false          | plain    |              | 
 geo_latitude          | double precision       |                                 | plain    |              | 
 geo_longitude         | double precision       |                                 | plain    |              | 
 languages             | integer[]              |                                 | extended |              | 
 created_at            | integer                |                                 | plain    |              | 
 updated_at            | integer                |                                 | plain    |              | 
 version               | bigint                 | default 0                       | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "advertiser_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

What is your advice? Where should I looking for the problem?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You aren't inserting a value for `id`. Since you don't explicitly set it, it's implicitly given a `null` value, which is, of course, not a valid value for a primary key column. You can avoid this entire situation by defining this column as `serial` instead of a plain old `integer`, and leave all the heavy lifting to the database.

Comment: what if I have already the column as serial? What could it be?

Comment: Or if your id column already has a sequence set, try inserting with the keyword DEFAULT instead of NULL.

Answer (score 11):

The `serial` keyword is expanded at parse time and cannot be seen afterward.

From the version `Postgresql 10` there is the following alternative:

```
id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
```

It is supposed to conform  to the SQL standard and thus be compatible with Oracle.

See this [blog](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/) for more details.

Comment: what is the difference between "by default" and "always" ?

Answer (score 6):

Happened to me after reading a PostgreSQL10 dump into 9.6 database server. After that, the sequences that are to auto-create sequential IDs were lost.

This can be shown like this (in psql):

```
SELECT  column_name
,       column_default
FROM    information_schema.columns
WHERE   table_name = 'django_migrations'
ORDER BY 
    ordinal_position;
```

where `django_migrations` is the table name. It should show something like this:

```
 column_name |                column_default                 
-------------+-----------------------------------------------
 id          | nextval('django_migrations_id_seq'::regclass)
[...]
```

If the value in 'column_default' is empty, then the sequence is lost.

Comment: how did you fix the issue?

Comment: I use a Mac, and there is Postgresql.app (www.postgresqlapp.com) which allows to install mutliple versions in parallel, so I can switch the DB server version on the fly. There should be a solution for Linux (and maybe even Windows), too

Answer (score 5):

If you can't change to `serial` because reasons like client, management, db rights...

The database is probably using `sequence`.

Here are what to know about it :  `SELECT nextval('seq_nuu_filtreelement')`

To read :

- http://www.neilconway.org/docs/sequences/
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE

I did not manage to make `pg_catalog.pg_get_serial_sequence('schema.table', 'id')` work.

Thus I found the sequences  in my database explorer and use the command :

`SELECT nextval('seq_table_name')`

Answer (score 4):

Change your existing primary key to `serial` . Read this for changing it

[Changing primary key int type to serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578427/changing-primary-key-int-type-to-serial)

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason, you cannot change your schema to change the type of your id column from whatever it is presently to `serialize`; then, you may insert the id along with the rest of your values like so:

`(select max(id) + 1 from table)`

Comment: Believe you mean SERIAL, not `serialize`

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't atomic. That is, two different requests trying to do this at the same time could come up with the same ID and then one will fail.

Comment: @jwadsack what workaround  do you suggest?

Comment: @asma-rahim-ali-jafri as @poutrathor stated, if you can't change the column type to `serial`, add a `sequence`, which is an atomic counter, and use `nextval()` to ensure that every insert gets a distinct row ID.

Comment: @jwadsack thank you for pointing out such a huge flaw and helping me learn something new!!

Comment: `nextval` technically has the reverse problem. It won't cause duplicates, but it can cause skipped values. This *should* not be a problem. SQL doesn't care. But your application logic should not assume contiguous ID's.

Answer (score 2):

Or if your id column already has a sequence set, try inserting with the keyword DEFAULT instead of NULL.

In MySQL, NULL would use the default value for a column, but not so in Postgres.

Your example query would be changed to this:

```
INSERT INTO "advertiser" ("languages", "type", "name", "display_name", "title", "about", "birthday", "gender", "country_id", "county_id", "city_id", "city_part", "street", "house_number", "phone", "public_email", "public_url", "motto", "message", "im_facebook", "im_skype", "has_viber", "has_whatsapp", "has_sms_response", "visible_birthday", "is_checked", "status", "version", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 'Demo', '', '', '', '1998-01-01', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', '', '345345435453453', '', '', '', '', '', '', FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 10, NULL, 1, 1470477479, 1470477479) RETURNING "id"
```

This answer shows using the DEFAULT keyword: [insert DEFAULT values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602992/insert-default-values)